# Session cookie still authenticates after app pool recycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, cookies

My ASP.NET MVC websites are staying signed in when I don't believe they should be.

My web server is IIS 7.5 and the app pool is V4.0 Integrated with idle-timeout set to 20 mins.

When logging in, the website saves an auth cookie that expires "When the browsing session ends" (persistence set to false).

If I close the browser (Chrome or FF) and then recycle (or stop/start) the app pool on IIS on the server, then reopen the browser, then session cookie still appears to be valid.

I know that Firefox and Chrome don't delete session cookies when you close the browser (so you can start where you left off), but surely the session doesn't exist on the server anymore, since the app pool has recycled? I'm not saving session data to a database, and don't have machine id's setup in my web.config.

Why is this cookie still valid?

## Edit 1 - how is the cookie set

Cookie auth options are set by ConfigureAuth (called from the Configuration method in my OWIN Startup class). Cookie options:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    CookieName = "MyCookieName",
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7) // this only applies if persistent is true!
});
```

The user is signed in using

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent, rememberBrowser);
```

`isPersistent` is set from the "Remember me" check box on the login form. If this is checked then the cookie expires using the ExpireTimeSpan from the `CookieAuthenticationOptions`. If it's not checked, the the cookie expires "When the browsing session ends", which is where my question lies.

`rememberBrowser` is set to false - this is used for 2FA which is not used in my implementation.

`SignInAsync` is the default implementation, which calls:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
      IsPersistent = isPersistent
    }, userIdentity);
```

...which is again the default implementation.

The `AuthenticationManager` takes care of setting the actual cookie (I believe).

## Edit 2 - machineKey?

Having looked into this further, it's possible that a machine key is being stored to the cookie, allowing it to authenticate across pool recycles. I have not defined a machineKey in the web.config, so I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: When you recycle the memory is cleared so technicaly this is impossible ;) Are you sure you are recycling the right application (happened to me, stupid me)

Comment: @Ravenix Yes, definitely recycling the correct app pool. This is why I'm so confused about how I'm staying logged in.

Comment: That can only mean that the session management is not in memory. Are you absolutely 100% sure that the session are saved in memory?

Comment: The app pool is using default settings (more or less) certainly changed nothing regarding memory management. As far as IIS itself - I wasn't involved in the installation, but it'd likely be a standard setup. I'm 99% that the sessions are saved in memory. I'll try to confirm and remove the 1% doubt.

Comment: Confirmed... 100% from the horses mouth (the guy who set the whole server up)

Comment: How are you creating the auth cookie and sending it to the browser? Are you using something like `SetAuthCookie` or encrypting the cookie using tickets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS identifies applications with a machine key that stays the same across app pool recycles. This is stored in the authentication cookie so that users can be authenticated across app pool recycles.